# SQL Server - Get closest value greater than a specific value

Tags: sql-server, match

I have a table containing the arrival time for each order.

Order_arrival_time

```
order_id   arrival_time
    1               120
    2               239
    3               500           
    ...
```

for each specific order, it has a number of truck depature time to choose which can be queried from the below table:

Truck_departure_time

```
Order_id     Truck_id           deppature_time
 1            truck_0             66
 1            truck_1             125
 1            truck_2             300
 1            truck_3             720
 1            truck_4             900
 1            ...
```

I want to match each order with the nearest truck depature time after it's arrival time like:

```
order_id   arrival_time    depature_time
    1               120          125
    2               239          300
    3               500          720   
    ...
```

Comment: Going to need a bit of effort on your part. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function as

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  OrderID INT,
  ArrivalTime INT
);

CREATE TABLE T2(
  OrderID INT,
  TruckID VARCHAR(45),
  DepartureTime INT
);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
(1 ,120),
(2 ,239),
(3 ,500);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
(1, 'truck_0' , 66),
(1, 'truck_1' , 125),
(1, 'truck_2' , 300),
(2, 'truck_3' , 720),
(2, 'truck_4' , 900);

WITH C AS
(
SELECT T1.OrderID,
       T1.ArrivalTime,
       T2.DepartureTime,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.OrderID ORDER BY T2.DepartureTime) RN
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
     ON T1.OrderID = T2.OrderID
)
SELECT OrderID,
       ArrivalTime,
       DepartureTime
FROM C
WHERE RN = 2;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| OrderID | ArrivalTime | DepartureTime |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |         120 |           125 |
|       2 |         239 |           900 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=762e3c08ed04d3fd8b0a292b5f572204)**

---

*UPDATE:*

```
SELECT T1.OrderID,
       T1.Arrivaltime,
       TT.DepartureTime
FROM
(
  SELECT T1.OrderID,
         T1.ArrivalTime,
         T2.DepartureTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.OrderID ORDER BY T1.OrderID) RN
  FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2
) TT INNER JOIN T1
ON T1.OrderID = TT.RN - 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+
| OrderID | Arrivaltime | DepartureTime |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |         120 |           125 |
|       2 |         239 |           300 |
|       3 |         500 |           720 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c642123619124fd97eaaf9f041ae1199)**

Comment: order_2 should be 720 rather than 900

Answer (score 0):

Get `departure_time` with a TOP 1 subquery with a WHERE clause that correlates to the `arrival_time`.

Or if you want to get fancier, you can probably use CROSS APPLY.

Comment: the depature time must be equal or greater than the arrival time.

Comment: Yes, I get that.  You want the first (top 1) departure time after each arrival time.